# Cannot resolve symbol setOnTouchListener

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

I want to set a touch event that only occurs when player object is touched. But why my player class still cannot use `setOnTouchListener` method? I put it in a main class that extends SurfaceView and implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, it says cannot resolve symbol on

```
player.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener){
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    };
```

My player class extends GameObject(Which is just an abstract class containing object properties) and implements View.OnTouchListener.
I have also override the method in the player class itself.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
```

Any idea? Thanks.

EDIT:

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
    bg = new Background(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.background));
    player = new Player(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.character),WIDTH/2,HEIGHT/2+40,80,75,14);
    safeArea = new SafeArea(WIDTH/2,HEIGHT/2,100,40);
    bouncer = new ArrayList<Bouncer>();

    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);

    //Start the game loop
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
    setOnTouchListener(player);
}
```

Comment: What do your imports look like?

Comment: in player class : import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View; @KristyWelsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said the `player`'s class implements `View.OnTouchListener`. Obviously `class View.OnTouchListener` does not has method `setOnTouchListener()`.

You should review your intention. Do you want `player` to implement `View` instead? Or whose `OnTouchListener` do you want to set actually?

Since your "main class" extends `SurfaceView`, it looks like you may want

```
setOnTouchListener(player);
```

which sets `player` as the OnTouchListener of the "main class" instance, which is also a `SurfaceView` and thus is a `View`.

To define `player.onTouch()`, you should define it inside class `Player` like:

```
class Player implements View.OnTouchListener // extends GameObject ?
{
    // ...
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement View only but it says that interface expected here, so I tried to implement View.OnTouchListener instead and thought that was going to be the same. My bad then, so is there any solution to this? Thanks

Comment: @user3411184 Updated. `View` can only be extended, but you've extended  `GameObject`. Thus I guess your intention as described in my answer.

Comment: wow thanks I think it's beginning to work, but just one more step, how to call the onTouch function? since now we don't set onTouch function  inside a setOnClickListener method anymore.

Comment: With `setOnTouchListener(player);`, `player.onTouch()` is called when "a touch event is sent to the view" represented by your "main class" instance as described in [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).

Comment: Excuse my lack of knowledge, but which item do I need to pass to both the View v and MotionEvent event parameter of the onTouch method? I have also written public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){return true;}

Comment: You don't call `onTouch()` by yourself. Android system calls it for you when the event happens.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear just now, but I've edited my post so you can see my "main class". the problem I'm facing now is that it says Method 'onTouch' is never used. Is there any other thing that I did wrong? I've also run my code and did Toast.makeText to see if it's working but it was not. Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused about what you want. If you want main class' `onTouch()` to be called when touch event happens (not player.onTouch()!), then you should make the main class implementing `interface View.OnTouchListener` and calls `setOnTouchListener(this)`. Please make sure who the listener should be to match your intention.

Comment: I'm truly sorry, you had my intention right, I forgot to write player.onTouch() instead of onTouch(). but It still does not work, can you please see my edited post again and tell me how to fix it? Thanks a lot and sorry

Comment: @user3411184 Described how to define `Player.onTouch()` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    OnTouchListener X_ol = new OnTouchListener() {
   @Override

    public boolean onTouch(View p_v, MotionEvent p_event) {

       if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
        //Insert desired code here
        return true;
    }
    return false;
    }
};

player.setOnTouchListener(X_ol);

 }
```